# Adding / removing maven dependancies in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am creating a new maven project in IntelliJ. It shows few predefined maven dependancies to be imported. I added new dependance and by mistake I added `>` sign into it(which I did not recognize it all dependancies were resolved.). Now I am getting build failure for the same.

Does anyone know how to remove this dependency?

1. pom.xml does not list any individual dependancies.
2. there is a file with .iml extension that as well does not list individual ones
3. Project structure -> dependancies does not list either
4. right click on pom does not have option to show dependancies

Any help will be appreciated.